# не удается создать экземпляр абстрактного класса или интерфейса "Item" c#

Tags: c#, класс

```
 abstract class Item
    { public Item(long invNumber, bool taken)
        {
            this.invNumber = invNumber;
            this.taken = taken;
        }
        public Item()
        {
            this.taken = true;
        }
     }
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Item item1 = new Item();/*Тут ошибка
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

> не удается создать экземпляр абстрактного класса

```
/*abstract*/ class Item
```

*Вслушайтесь в эти слова: "Тиха украинская ночь, прозрачно небо ..."*

Comment: тем не менее, в лабораторной просят сделать именно так "Реализуйте класс Item как абстрактный"

Comment: @ававава Мне сквозь компьютер плохо видно Вашу лабораторную.

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно. По законам ООП нельзя создавать экземпляры абстрактного класса. Это как создать человека из мысли о человеке.

Comment: тем не менее, в лабораторной просят сделать именно так "Реализуйте класс Item как абстрактный"

Comment: @ававава да ради бога. Только вот создавать надо из *реального* класса. Т.е. нужно создать ещё класс, который наследуется от абстрактного и уже создавать экземпляр этого самого класса, а не абстрактного

Comment: Под "реализуйте класс Item как абстрактный" имеется ввиду добавить абстрактный класс Item с некоторыми его членами. Не нужно создавать экземпляр абстрактного класса (этого делать нельзя).

Comment: @Danila вы это кому написали?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я написал @ав….

Comment: @Danila тогда надо было его тегать ;-)  В ином случае сообщение он не получит.... А вообще комментарии не дискуссии

Answer (score 0):

Что бы создать объект класса, класс должен быть не абстрактным. Просто создайте новый класс, которые является наследником `Item`.

[Про абстрактные классы в c#](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.8.php)

Comment: а что я туда должен написать?

Comment: @ававава `class ItemA : Item {...}`

Comment: @ававава а вы можете добавить в ответ всё задание текстом?

Comment: Реализуйте класс Item как абстрактный
 Добавьте ключевое слово abstract при объявлении класса
abstract class Item
Производные классы не обязаны переопределять виртуальные методы, но

если требуется обязать переопределять виртуальный метод, то его следует сде-
лать абстрактным. Методы, помеченные как abstract, являются чистым прото-
колом: они просто определяют имя, возвращаемый тип (если есть), и набор па-
раметров (при необходимости).Реализуйте метод Return как абстрактный
 Добавьте ключевое слово abstract при объявлении метода Return
базового класса и удалите тело класса:

Comment: abstract public void Return();
 Протестируйте вызов абстрактного метода
 В методе Main класса Program вызовите абстрактный метод:

53

Item it;
it = b2;
it.TakeItem();
it.Return();
it.Show();
it = mag1;
it.TakeItem();
it.Return();
it.Show();

Comment: @ававава у вас написано `Item it; it = b2;`, тут b2 - это `new B()` или что такое, где `B` - унаследованный класс от `Item`, который переопределяет (или нет) виртуальные методы `Item`